# Android - ProGuard causing warnings from all JavascriptInterface uses

Tags: javascript, android, webview, proguard

I have seen lots of problems with using ProGuard on applications that include webviews with JavascriptInterfaces, but none of the solutions seem to work for me so I must be missing something.

I have this activity

```
public class MapviewActivity extends Activity {
     private WebView webView;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.webview_map);
          getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          getActionBar().setTitle("The Map");

          webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.map_webview);
          webView.clearCache(true);
          webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
          webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
          webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

          webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
          webView.setInitialScale(1);

          webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
          webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.html");

          webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MapviewJSInterface(this), "Android");

     }

     public class MapviewJSInterface {
         public Context mContext;

         public MapviewJSInterface(MapviewActivity mapviewActivity) {
           this.mContext = mapviewActivity;
         }

         @JavascriptInterface
         public void showResidents(String locCode) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DialogResidentsList.class);
           intent.putExtra("colorString", locCode);
           mContext.startActivity(intent);
         }
     }
 }
```

my proguard-project.txt includes this

```
-keep class tv.cmc2.zaratancodex.controller.MapviewActivity$MapviewJSInterface
-keepclassmembers class tv.cmc2.zaratancodex.controller.MapviewActivity$MapviewJSInterface {
    public void showResidents(java.lang.String);
}
```

but I keep getting this error when I try to export an apk

```
Warning: tv.cmc2.zaratancodex.view.MapviewActivity$MapviewJSInterface: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
```

there must be something else that I am missing because those are the rules that seem to be working for everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build against a version of the Android runtime that contains the class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface. That would be android-17 or higher. ProGuard then won't complain that it can't find it.

If your code uses the annotation to mark Javascript interface classes (as required in recent versions of the Android SDK), you can also use it in your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

You then no longer need to exhaustively list the interface classes and methods.

Comment: perfect.  I had tried building against 17 before, but I didn't add any -keep statements so even though it would build, the functionality would be broken. Now it works, Thank you